# Simple Artificial Intelligence Search Problem Infinite Loop Bug in Python

Tags: python, debugging, search, artificial-intelligence, infinite-loop

I am working on Project 0 for Harvard's CS50 Artificial Intelligence class and we had to write a function called shortest_path which is used in the program in finding the shortest path between two actors in a movie database based on shared movies they have worked on with other actors.  I did write the function but am getting an infinite loop and can't figure out why I am getting it.  I followed the directions from lecture where it says to only add a node to the frontier if the node does not exist in the frontier and also does not exist in previously explored nodes. Overlooking this is something that could lead to an infinite loop but I am still getting one. The test case I used is when the name of the source actor is Kevin and target actor is Kevin. I just pick two different Kevins from the list that's provided after entering Kevin as sources first and targets first name. I am posting my shortest_path function and a link where the rest of the project files can be downloaded with the relevant CSV files for the data being used to test the project.

Link to project files: Download the distribution code from https://cdn.cs50.net/ai/2020/x/projects/0/degrees.zip and unzip it.

The only function we had to modify was the shortest_path function in the distribution code provided so that's all I am posting, along with the classes for the node and Queuefrontier data structure being used. The rest of the code is in the distribution files in case you need to see how it all fits into place.

My code for shortest_path function:

```
def shortest_path(source, target):
    """
    Returns the shortest list of (movie_id, person_id) pairs
    that connect the source to the target.

    If no possible path, returns None.
    """
    path = []

    # Keep track of number of states explored
    num_explored = 0

    # Initialize frontier to just the starting position
    start = Node(state=source, parent=None, action=None)
    frontier = QueueFrontier()
    frontier.add(start)

    # Initialize an empty explored set
    explored = set()

    # Keep looping until solution found
    counter = 0
    while True:
        print(counter)
        counter = counter + 1
        # If nothing left in frontier, then no path
        if frontier.empty():
                return None

        # Choose a node from the frontier
        node = frontier.remove()
        num_explored += 1

        # If node is the goal, then we have a solution
        if node.state == target:
            actions = []
            cells = []       
            path=[]
            while node.parent is not None:
                #actions.append(node.action)
                #cells.append(node.state)
                path.append(node.action,node.state)
                node = node.parent
            #actions.reverse()
            #cells.reverse()
            path.reverse()
            #solution = (actions, cells)
            return path

        # Mark node as explored
        explored.add(node.state)

        # Add neighbors to frontier
        for action, state in neighbors_for_person(node.state):
            if not frontier.contains_state(state) and state not in explored:
                child = Node(state=state, parent=node, action=action)
                frontier.add(child)
```

Code for Class Node and QueueFrontier:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, state, parent, action):
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.action = action
    def toString(self):
        print(f"State={self.state}, Parent={self.parent}")

class StackFrontier():
    def __init__(self):
        self.frontier = []

    def add(self, node):
        self.frontier.append(node)

    def contains_state(self, state):
        return any(node.state == state for node in self.frontier)

    def empty(self):
        return len(self.frontier) == 0

    def remove(self):
        if self.empty():
            raise Exception("empty frontier")
        else:
            node = self.frontier[-1]
            self.frontier = self.frontier[:-1]
            return node


class QueueFrontier(StackFrontier):

    def remove(self):
        if self.empty():
            raise Exception("empty frontier")
        else:
            node = self.frontier[0]
            self.frontier = self.frontier[1:]
            return node
```

Comment: Remember that SO likes you to have had a really good go at solving your problem before helping with homework. You mention in the title that there is an infinite loop - how do you know its infinite? could it be that the code is very slow and needs to run longer. If it truly is infinite, that means you never reach your exit condition (`if frontier.empty()` or `if node.state == target`) so I would add some debugging code to explore what values each of those takes as your code runs.

Comment: @Pepsi-Joe: I did do that, I have debugging code - I added a counter that prints the count and when I was testing it, the counter reached like 100 digits long - however large that number is, it was taking up 4 lines to print each value of the counter.  I tried debugging on my own and couldn't figure it out is why I asked on SO. Also, it isn't homework per say as the class is just for learning purposes, it isn't for a grade or anything like that. Its a free online class offered by Harvard.

Comment: If your counter is getting up to such large numbers after you fixed the code so it doesn't grow exponentially, then it must be getting into a loop. I would probe `node.state` and make sure that it giving you a unique element for each counter value. If it is not, then you will likely be in some kind of loop where your code is going something like Node A -> Node B -> Node C -> Node A.